# Java-style package naming and second-level country domains

Tags: naming, packages

I own a .co.uk domain, and I whenever I've dealt with Java-style package naming, I've gone with `uk.co.domainname`. Once I encountered package that did the following: `co.uk.domainname`.

Is one of these right, or is it something that's up to the developer's discretion? Is there some sort of convention that deals with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real rule here, just the conventions that Sun created with the com.sun.* packagers.  The only real requirement is uniqueness and that the co.uk... convention defines a folder/file structure.

What will be the decider in your case is what name you want for a 'root' folder - 'uk' or 'co'?

Comment: Thanks, that sounds fair enough. Though having packages with both co.uk.* and uk.co.* in the same project does seem very.. messy.

Comment: Right - whatever you choose, be consistent.  (Not being consistent with package naming can cause real headaches, like java files split into different roots, issues with testing protected methods, etc,)

Comment: I meant specifically when you have to use a third-party package and it uses co.uk.* while you're using uk.co.*. In which case I guess it's purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 8):

[Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) make it pretty clear that you should use the inverse of your domain name, e.g. `uk.co.domainname`. If you mix it up and go with `co.uk.domainname` then you run the risk of someone with the site http://uk.co clashing with your package naming structure. While unlikely, you may as well stick to the standards and rule any potential clash out.